# TortoiseSVN returning Error running context: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: svn, parameters, tortoisesvn

I am using TortoiseSVN on Windows 7 for an HTTP repository. I could always access it and was working on it until two days ago. The credentials used are the same with the Windows Domain and I can still access the repositories from the browser. I had to change the Windows password and after that, every action I try to perform on the code (Check Out, Commit, Use Repo Browser) returns the errors **Unable to connect to a repository at URL** and **Error running context: The parameter is incorrect.** I am attaching a screenshot of it, as well.

I have tried clearing all Stored Data, uninstalling and reinstalling, uninstalling and reinstalling a different version, uninstalling and then deleting manually every folder and every related Registry entry which contained "Tortoise" and then reinstalling the latest version 1.9.4, but it always returns this error. I have also checked with the System Administrator and post-checking my credentials there is no issue, as I can confirm it myself, as well, since I can login properly when I enter the same URL on the browser. I have also tried changing the protocol to HTTPS or SVN, still same result.

What I noticed is that there is no data in the folder:

> AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple

There are no files in any of the subfolders of "auth".

I have really ran out of ideas and I haven't found anything else by googling, as for most clearing the Stored Data was sufficient for the software to run.

So, I have two questions:
A. Has anyone experienced this before? If yes, how did you resolve it?
B. I fear, the software is trying to access the repository without any authentication and that is why it is returning those errors. How can I force it to prompt me to use my credentials?

[image: The errors I see on TortoiseSVN when I try to perform any action]

Answer (score 0):

Eventually i stuck to similar error and after wasting 1 day I managed to solve this.

I followed these steps(open command prompt as administrator and run):
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew

netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset

After that restart the computer and :D SVN was working.

Hope this helps.